# SparkFiles.get() method fails to find as Input Split adds strings at the end

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I am running a spark job and its in cluster mode. So, my driver downloads files, adds them to all executor `SparkSession.sparkContext.addFile("file:///" + file.toString)` *Note:* `file` *here is* `java.io.File` Object. Now I call `sc.textFile("file:///"+SparkFiles.get(fileName)` *Note:* `fileName` *is actually* `file.getName` *which returns the file name of the* `java.io.File` *object*. I get a file not found exception. the size of the files are less than 500kb. I tried reading the yarn logs and found this.

```
10:35:17 INFO executor.Executor: Fetching spark://foo.bar.ca:45133/files/QQ4hyC.csv with timestamp 1562250908486
19/07/04 10:35:17 INFO client.TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to foo.bar.ca/102.63.12.200:45000 after 1 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
19/07/04 10:35:17 INFO util.Utils: Fetching spark://foo.bar.ca:45133/files/QQ4hyC.csv to /data15/yarn/nm/usercache/networkhadoop/appcache/application_1559671533076_152651/spark-d0ee1f52-0b3d-4f28-8c40-31283fbc6c00/fetchFileTemp6119089786950130363.tmp
19/07/04 10:35:17 INFO util.Utils: Copying /data15/yarn/nm/usercache/networkhadoop/appcache/application_1559671533076_152651/spark-d0ee1f52-0b3d-4f28-8c40-31283fbc6c00/-20762980841562250908486_cache to /data19/yarn/nm/usercache/networkhadoop/appcache/application_1559671533076_152651/container_e94_1559671533076_152651_01_000002/./QQ4hyC.csv
19/07/04 10:35:17 INFO executor.Executor: Fetching spark://foo.bar.ca:45133/files/20mo2V.csv with timestamp 1562250908498
19/07/04 10:35:17 INFO util.Utils: Fetching spark://foo.bar.ca:45133/files/20mo2V.csv to /data15/yarn/nm/usercache/networkhadoop/appcache/application_1559671533076_152651/spark-d0ee1f52-0b3d-4f28-8c40-31283fbc6c00/fetchFileTemp4236523310531688097.tmp
19/07/04 10:35:17 INFO util.Utils: Copying /data15/yarn/nm/usercache/networkhadoop/appcache/application_1559671533076_152651/spark-d0ee1f52-0b3d-4f28-8c40-31283fbc6c00/-3045146541562250908498_cache to /data19/yarn/nm/usercache/networkhadoop/appcache/application_1559671533076_152651/container_e94_1559671533076_152651_01_000002/./20mo2V.csv
19/07/04 10:35:17 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 2
19/07/04 10:35:17 INFO client.TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to foo.bar.ca/102.63.12.200:46650 after 5 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
19/07/04 10:35:17 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.2 KB, free 912.3 MB)
19/07/04 10:35:17 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Reading broadcast variable 2 took 148 ms
19/07/04 10:35:18 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.6 KB, free 912.3 MB)
19/07/04 10:35:18 INFO rdd.HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/data20/yarn/nm/usercache/networkhadoop/appcache/application_1559671533076_152651/spark-28989d25-5d6e-4e49-8513-699d01ac0976/userFiles-dd2b37d9-0029-486e-9c55-84703887b1ca/QQ4hyC.csv:0+48343
19/07/04 10:35:18 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 0
19/07/04 10:35:18 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 31.5 KB, free 912.3 MB)
19/07/04 10:35:18 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Reading broadcast variable 0 took 27 ms
19/07/04 10:35:18 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 512.6 KB, free 911.8 MB)
19/07/04 10:35:19 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/data20/yarn/nm/usercache/networkhadoop/appcache/application_1559671533076_152651/spark-28989d25-5d6e-4e49-8513-699d01ac0976/userFiles-dd2b37d9-0029-486e-9c55-84703887b1ca/QQ4hyC.csv does not exist
```

If you look at `INFO util.Utils: Copying` you can see that it is indeed being copied from `/data15/...` to `/data19/...`, but it throws file not found at `/data19/...`
From the official docs it seems `SparkContext.addFiles()` adds files to workers and `SparkFiles.get()` can get it from the worker nodes to which this was copied. Is this a bug?

Comment: I always try and use the products as designed to be.

Comment: The files are small in size and so didn't want them on HDFS. Btw, what would you suggest?